# Java - Cannot resolve constructor

Tags: java

I am new to Java programming. I have three classes which are `Main`, `Point` and `Rectangle`. I can use all constructors in `Rectangle` class except this one: `Rectangle(Point p, int w, int h)`. Java compiler gives: "Cannot resolve constructor 'Rectangle(java.awt.Point, int, int)'" error. Thanks.

Here my classes:

Main.java

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Rectangle;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Point originOne = new Point(5,10);   
        Rectangle rectOne = new Rectangle(originOne, 100, 200);
    }

}
```

Point.java

```
public class Point {
    public int x = 0;
    public int y = 0;
    //contructor
    public Point(int a, int b){
        x = a;
        y = b;
    }
}
```

Rectangle.java

```
public class Rectangle {
    public Point origin;
    public int width = 0;
    public int height = 0;

    //four contructors
    public Rectangle() {
        origin = new Point(0, 0);
    }
    public Rectangle(Point p){
        origin = p;
    }
    public Rectangle(int w, int h){
        origin = new Point(0,0);
        width = w;
        height = h;
    }
    public Rectangle(Point p, int w, int h) {
        origin = p;
        width = w;
        height = h;
    }

    // a method for moving the rectangle
    public void move(int x, int y) {
        origin.x = x;
        origin.y = y;
    }

    //a method for computing the area of rectangle
    public int getArea() {
        return width * height;
    }
}
```

Comment: You imported `java.awt.Point` which is an existing class of the Java AWT Toolkit. You need to import your own `Point` class (with whatever its complete package name is) is you want to use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your answer is fairly simple. You've imported the wrong import, rather than import `java.awt.Rectangle`, import your own class.

By doing:

```
import <nameOfTheProject>.Rectangle;
```

If I had a project in Eclipse called MyShapes and had the same classes. I would import it like:

```
import MyShapes.Rectangle;
```

Now this obviously depends on how your file structure is, but if it's inside a sub-folder (sub-package), I would do like:

```
import MyShapes.ShapesClasses.Rectangle;
```

**This also applies to the Point class if you're planning on using your own Point class and not Java.awt's one!**

Comment: Note that a) package names do not necessarily match Eclipse project names (in fact, by convention they don't) and that b) they are supposed to be all lower-case.

Comment: Haha, yes! That's right, I forgot to mention I personally create a package within /src folder in Eclipse where I place all of my code so I can distinguish my custom imports from Java ones.

Comment: nothing wrong with that, but going with a "com.<your-name>.<project-name>" prefix would be more consistent with usual Java conventions